# Moving from @ManagedBean to @Named fails to run @PostConstruct

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, cdi, jsf-2.2

I had a JSF app using @ManagedBean working great, but I tried to migrate to @Named/@Inject and now the @PostConstruct methods aren't loading.  I updated all the imports so that the JSF scopes weren't being imported but nothing I do gets the beans to load.  When I look in the JBoss EAP 6.2 logs I see the bean being recognized as a managed bean.  Tomcat 8 doesn't say anything.  I feel like I'm missing something simple.  Here's one of my beans:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ScaleUser {

.
.
.

@PostConstruct
    public void init()  {
    logger.error("IN POST CONSTRUCT");
```

And in my JSF page:

```
<a href="user.xhtml">#{scaleUser.displayName}</a>
```

Comment: What are packages of annotations? Is your bean still registered in faces-config.xml? EAP 6.2 means Java EE 6. Have you added beans.xml to WEB-INF directory?

Comment: So I think I know the answer but I'm not going to mark this as answered because I haven't verified it.  I originally migrated this app to CDI because the generic JSF annotations weren't working in tomcat and had read that the JSF annotations were deprecated.  However, I found out tomcat wasn't loading my \@ManagedBean annotations because they were in jar files and needed faces-config.xml in each jar.  Once I did that \@ManagedBean worked great.  I suspect that putting beans.xml in each jar would have gotten this to work as well.

Comment: You are right, you need to include at least empty beans.xml to turn on CDI mechanism. This is with EAP 6.2, which supports only Java EE 6. If running on a Java EE 7 server, beans.xml is not necessary, as marking scope with `@SessionScoped` would be sufficient to turn on injection for `ScaleUser`